# PHP anonymous class without instance

Tags: php, oop, anonymous-class, php-7

Is there a way of declaring an anonymous class that has no instance?

I'd like to do something like this:

```
$myclass = (class {
    public $a;
})::class;

$myobject = new $myclass;
```

This is something you can do with named classes, but the above code throws a syntax error.

Comment: The error you get tells you what is wrong. Once you fixed that you will get the error telling you that no, what you want is not possible. `Fatal error: Dynamic class names are not allowed in compile-time ::class fetch in` neither would it make that much sense.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/mcKc7

Comment: @PeeHaa Thanks. It would make sense for me, I'd like to test named constructors on subclasses of an abstract class. I'd like to make many different subclasses and I wouldn't like to pollute my tests file with them

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally, I was able to make a workaround thanks to [this comment](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.anonymous.php#119153) at php.net

```
$myclass = get_class(new class {
    public $a;
});

$myobject = new $myclass;
```

Comment: Why can't you just do `$myclass = new class { public $a; };`?

Comment: @PeeHaa Because I'd like to use named constructors like: `$myobject = $myclass::fromString('abc')` where `fromString` returns a new instance

Comment: This workaround simply creates an instance and then get the class from this instance. So it is not « without instance ».